# How to get the sum of a created column from a joined table? SQL / C#

Tags: asp.net, sql, join, textbox, sum

In ASP.NET / C#, I am working with two tables; Cart_LineItems and Products. I have joined the two tables and created a new column called "Extension" that has multiplied the "Products.UnitPrice" times the "Cart_LineItems.Quantity". This is my full SQL query.

```
SELECT Cart_LineItems.ProductID, Products.Name, Products.UnitPrice, 
     Cart_LineItems.Quantity, Products.UnitPrice * Cart_LineItems.Quantity 

AS Extension, Cart_LineItems.CartNumber 
FROM (Cart_LineItems 
INNER JOIN Products 
ON Cart_LineItems.ProductID = Products.ProductID) 
WHERE (Cart_LineItems.CartNumber = ?)
```

This query is working fine and fills the GridView the way I want it to. How do I get the sum of the fields in the "Extension" column and put the results in a TextBox on a web form?

This is the C# code That I am using in the code behind class.

```
 String strAddSQL = "";

 strAddSQL = "SELECT SUM(extension) as subtotal FROM (Cart_LineItems 
     INNER JOIN Products ON Cart_LineItems.ProductID = Products.ProductID)";

    OleDbConnection myAddConn = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbDataReader myAddReader;
    myAddConn.ConnectionString = this.SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString;
    OleDbCommand myAddCmd = new OleDbCommand(strAddSQL, myAddConn);
    myAddConn.Open();
    myAddReader = myAddCmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (myAddReader.Read())
    {
        txtSubTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(myAddReader["subtotal"]);

    }
    myAddReader.Close();
    myAddConn.Close();
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you should try this type:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int sum = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    sum += (int)dr[dc];
                }
            }
```